# Dojo layout rendering problem

Tags: layout, dojo, render

Press F5 in this example: [DojoToolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.html).

First the content is shown, and after that the layout gets into it's final state. In my application I want the opposite, so that the layout gets rendered, and after that the content is displayed. I don't want that 'jumping' phenomenon when loading. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think that there is such an option. Anyway, you could use a container div (with all the dojo layout elements in it) with initial state `visbility:hidden`, and after the page is loaded and parsed change it's visibility to "visible".

```
    <div id="container" style="visibility:hidden">
      <!-- dijit widgets inside the "container"-->
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.ready(function(){
        dojo.style("container:, "visibility", "visible");
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it gives a much nicer result. It's important for me because my application will be displayed as a desktop app, where the loading would be weird.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)